# Update in Entity Framework using IUnitOfWork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and `IUnitOfWork` to not repeat code, my `Add` is Ok, the problem is to do `Update`.

I get this error:

> Attaching an entity of type 'ViewModelTicket' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

I am using this `BaseContext` class:

```
public class BaseContext<T> : DbContext where T : class
{
    public DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public BaseContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        //Caso a base de dados não tenha sido criada, 
        //ao iniciar a aplicação iremos criar
        Database.SetInitializer<BaseContext<T>>(null);
    }

    public virtual void ChangeObjectState(object model, EntityState state)
    {
        //Aqui trocamos o estado do objeto, 
        //facilita quando temos alterações e exclusões
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
                      .ObjectContext
                      .ObjectStateManager
                      .ChangeObjectState(model, state);
    }

    public virtual int Save(T model)
    {
        this.DbSet.Add(model);
        return this.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual int Update(T model)
    {
        var entry = this.Entry(model);

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            this.DbSet.Attach(model);

        this.ChangeObjectState(model, EntityState.Modified);

        return this.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual T GetById(object id)
    {
        return this.DbSet.Find(id);
    }
}
```

The `IUnitWork` interface:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<T> where T : class
{
    int Save(T model);
    int Update(T model);
    void Delete(T model);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(object id);
    int Max();
    IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
    IEnumerable<T> OrderBy(Expression<System.Func<T, bool>> expression);
}
```

The controller method:

```
public ActionResult SavedTicket(Models.Ticket.ViewModelTicket ticket)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (this.UnitOfTicket.GetById(ticket.TicketId) == null) {
                ticket.TicketId = Convert.ToInt32( UnitOfTicket.Max());
                ticket.OpenDateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
                this.UnitOfTicket.Save(ticket);
            } else {
                this.UnitOfTicket.Update(ticket);
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(NewTicket));
        }
        else {
            return View(nameof(NewTicket), ticket);
        }
}
```

Thank you

EDIT

I solved the problem with this.

```
public virtual int Update(T model, int id)
{
   var entity = DbSet.Find(id);
   this.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
   return this.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: Do you even need another unit of work on top of DbContext which is a unit of work already?  What purpose does it serve? it looks like you are trying to get around using view models and sending entities directly to your views.  A better solution would be to actually use view models and map them back to entities instead of this whole detatch/attach scenario.

Comment: I followed this article http://netcoders.com.br/implementando-o-design-pattern-repository-e-unit-of-work-com-entity-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you generate the next higher Id when inserting a new entity?

```
//                                                    vvv
ticket.TicketId = Convert.ToInt32( UnitOfTicket.Max() + 1 );
```

Comment: public int Max() => DbSet.Max(x => x.TicketId) + 1;

Comment: Then it should be named `Next` or `NextId`! How is `GetById` implemented? (Could return `null` when it shouldn't)

Comment: The first "if" is to know if object exist or not if exists then update() else Add()

Comment: GetById is above

Comment: Try to change the state with `entry.State = state; `. See: [Entity Framework Add and Attach and Entity States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).